# NOT have axes ranges dynamically update when toggling a trace in plotly (turn off axis autoscaling)?

Tags: r, plotly

The default behavior of plotly is to scale axes automatically upon toggling a trace. How to counter this behavior?

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

data("tips")

fig <- plot_ly(tips, x = ~total_bill, y = ~tip, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', split = ~sex) %>%
  layout( plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6',
          xaxis = list(
            zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
            zerolinewidth = 2,
            gridcolor = 'ffff'),
          yaxis = list(
            zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
            zerolinewidth = 2,
            gridcolor = 'ffff'))
fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to disable the `autorange` and specify a `range` for both axis like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

data("tips")

fig <- plot_ly(tips, x = ~total_bill, y = ~tip, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', split = ~sex) %>%
  layout( plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6',
          xaxis = list(
            zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
            zerolinewidth = 2,
            gridcolor = 'ffff',
            autorange = FALSE,
            range = c(0, 50)),
          yaxis = list(
            zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
            zerolinewidth = 2,
            gridcolor = 'ffff', 
            autorange = FALSE,
            range = c(0, 7)))
fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

When you click on the legend, you will see that it doesn't autoscale the axis.

Comment: is there a way to not specify the ranges for axes beforehand?